# Tracing with micronaut not resumed when there is a backend outage for a while

Tags: micronaut, jaeger, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I am using micronaut for an application and exporting traces to jaeger backend. The traces export is working only if jaeger is available when application comesup.
Say if jaeger is brought up after app, or say if jaeger gets restarted, the traces are not exported

Is this expected or any specific configuration to be made in micronaut. I am following as specified in doc

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#jaeger

Answer (score 0):

After a few trails, I understood the behavior. If the host is available when the micronaut application comes up, traces are captured even if the host does not serve the trace listener.